# Meteor simple-schema validation on empty instances of a class

Tags: meteor

I actually posted this on the simple-schema Github issues w/ no response.  My code could be wrong, or my understanding of JS OOP could be wrong, as I come from a Java and PHP background.  So I'm not sure if this is a bug, but it seems that:

`check({}, Schema.User)` would trigger an exception, since the empty object is lacking required fields, but `check(new User(), Schema.User)` would be valid

isn't `new User()` supposed to have no values for required fields as well?

Here's also a quick experiment I did:

```
it("does not validate correctly if i give it an instance", function() {
  var Bee, b, schema;
  schema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      optional: false
    }
  });

  Bee = function() {};
  b = new Bee();

  schema.newContext().validate(b, {modifier: false}).should.be.false  // validate is true here
});

it("works if i give it {}", function() {
  var schema;
  schema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      optional: false
    }
  });

  schema.newContext().validate({}, {modifier: false}).should.be.false  // validate is false here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is intentional, and seems to validate only basic objects (so it validates `{}`, but not `new Bee()`) because of `else if (Utility.isBasicObject(val) ...` somewhere in the simple-schema-validation.js code.